# Should we also create indexes on views too for performance in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing, view

I am kinda new to programming... so I wonder is it required to provide indexes on views for performance issues?

Comment: I dont thik so, as view is just an script whihc read the data from tables.

Comment: "Normal" views in SQL Server cannot be indexed - so no, you should not add indexes to views for performance reasons - you need to properly index the underlying tables instead

Answer (score 0):

Required is a very big word in SQL Server. Its not required if the underlying tables (of the view) have indexes that can be used by the query effectively. Many developers do create indexes on views because of the gain in performance. There is a price to pay in terms of storage (the same data is now stored in the original table and in the view and the space taken up by the indexes) and in maintenance of the indexes. So the answer, as usual, is it depends....

There are also extensive (not impossible but) requirements to create an indexed view - see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28v=sql.80%29.aspx